# Running shell script only if parallel backgrounded scripts complete successfully

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have 4 bash scripts:

```
script1.sh
script2.sh
script3.sh
wrapper.sh
```

I want script1.sh and script2.sh to run in background. script1.sh and script2.sh should run at the same time (script2.sh should run even if script1.sh fails or vice versa). I want script3.sh to run only if script1.sh and script2.sh completes successfully.

wrapper.sh script should run all 3 scripts.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: `script2.sh` should run even if `script1.sh` fails?

Comment: See [this question](http://superuser.com/q/619016/107862) for one of the things you can use for this.

Comment: edited question, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `warpper.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# execute script1.sh in background and save pid in $pid1
./script1.sh &
pid1=$!

# execute script2.sh in background and save pid in $pid2
./script2.sh &
pid2=$!

# do more work here...

# wait for both background jobs to finish and save their return status
wait $pid1 && wait $pid2 && ./script3.sh
```

Comment: `wait $pid1 && wait $pid2 && script3.sh`?

Comment: Hm... actually I don't know if that's fully equivalent. The lack of the second `wait` if the first script fails may not be fully expected. You might want `wait $pid1; ret=$?; wait $pid2 && [ $ret -eq 0 ] && ./script3.sh` instead.

Comment: But I think OP wants script3 to not to run if either of first 2 scripts fail so I guess not waiting for script2 if script1 fails might be fine.

Comment: It might be. That's why I said "may not be fully expected". I also wan't entirely clear what would happen to `script2.sh` if `wrapper.sh` exited out from on top of it (if there are cases where it might care about that for example).